# Can't add static lib

Tags: c++, dll, linker, openssl, static-libraries

I am trying to build a DLL and it needs to reference a library namely libeay32.dll from the openssl package. I cant seem to add it as a reference under the Property Pages->Common Properties->Add New Reference because it gives error "Could not add a reference to file 'C:\OpenSSL\libeay32.dll' because it is neither a .NET assembly or registered Active X Control. I can compile and run it when I use the Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies and set the static lib 'C:\OpenSSL\lib\libeay32.lib'. But the end result is I need to include the libeay32.dll also.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I propose to tag it with ssl, openssl tags

Answer (score 4):

You're doing everything correctly. "Add Reference" is for .NET assemblies (and COM components used via .NET COM interop). The second approach that you've tried is the correct way to do this for native code, but `libeay32.lib` is not a static library; it's an export library for the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

As Pavel metioned, libeay32.lib is not the full library that your application can be statically linked against and run. It's used to resolve reference to the dynamic lib, dll. So, your app still need the dll to run.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0z8kac4.aspx

Comment: OK so what I was meaning to do is to build a DLL that does some encryption using functions from the OpenSSL package. But I want to make the build so the DLL can include(or merge?) the required libeay32.dll from openssl so the customer doesnt need to worry about having libeay32.dll already. Isnt there any simple way to do this or do I really need to rebuild the source for OpenSSL with my own project?

Comment: You can release libeay32.dll along with your dll. 
If you prefer to distribute the dll as a single file, you have to use static lib version of openssl. If it's not already provided, you need to rebuild it.
The "Configuration Type" property of the project controls whether to build a dynamic or static library.